Why do Ruby ERB if statements set variables to nil?
I'm using ERB to generate a set of instructions with location data, and want to accept an offset in my input. When I try to check if that offset is present however, it sets it's value to nil. If anyone can help explain what's going on it'd be greatly appreciated!
Here's the code I ran to test this, once I'd narrowed down the problem:
<%
    # apply a default value of 0 to the offset hash
    p offset.nil?
    p offset
    p offset.nil?
    p offset

    if offset.nil?
        p "I ran the code inside the if statement"
        offset = {}
        p "offset has been initialized, since it was nil"
    end

    p offset.nil?
    p offset
%>

and the output:
false
{"z"=>-10}
false
{"z"=>-10}
true
nil

If I delete the if statement, I get the expected result of:
false
{"z"=>-10}
false
{"z"=>-10}
false
{"z"=>-10}

but having that if statement (or one like it) is kind of important. I've figured out a workaround with a begin-rescue block that basically does what the If was supposed to do, but I'm very curious why this was happening.

are you sure you have if offset.nil? and not something like if offset = nil

Triple check that is the code you're actually executing.

if offset == nil gives the same result; and after triple checking, that is the code I am executing

sorry @Alex I misread your question,  I'm using if offset.nil? exactly, no typo

this same code behaves just fine in regular ruby, it's only within the ERB that I get this problem

I copy pasted your code, added offset = :foo at the start and ran it with erb file.erb and I cannot reproduce this.

What version of erb and ruby?

ruby 2.7.0, I'm not sure how to check my erb version

@Dogbert I tried it too, and it seems that if I define offset in the ERB it works fine, it's only when offset is passed into the template that the problems occur.

Seems like a problem with your indentation.
Try instead: writing each line betwee <% %> instead of using multiple line and go from there to figure out why yours didn't work

@DanielCusumano can you create a minimal example that reproduces the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Ruby 2.7.0 is quite out of date, you might have simply hit a Ruby bug. Try at least the latest 2.7, 2.7.8, which will have bug fixes.

gem list will show you all your gems and their version.

Please show us how you're running the erb.

I assume that at the beginning, when calling offset you are calling a method which returns the {"z"=>-10} value, e.g. method in an included helper module.
Now, in Ruby local variables have precedence before  methods with the same name. Thus, if there is a local variable named offset, when referencing this name, you are  getting the value of that variable rather than the result of calling the method of the same name.
Now, in Ruby when you define any code which may set a variable, this variable is initialized with nil, even if the code which sets an initial value is never actually run. This is similar to variable hoisting in JavaScript (but not entirely):
defined?(some_variable)
# => nil

if false
  some_variable = 'value'
end

defined?(some_variable)
# => "local-variable"

Thus, because you set offset = {} in the body of your if block, afterwards, you have a local offset variable in existence which shadows the offset method.
If you want to always call the offset method, you can instruct Ruby to call the method by adding parentheses (which are otherwise optional)
p offset
# => {"z"=>-10}

if offset.nil?
  offset = {}
end

p offset
# => nil
p defined?(offset)
# => "local-variable"

p offset()
# => {"z"=>-10}
p defined?(offset())
# => "method"

To implement your actual use-case, you could also use something like this instead of your if statement in order to set the offset variable as either the result of the offset method or an empty hash if the method returns nil or false:
offset = offset() || {}


That makes sense, and your implementation works perfectly. Thanks for the answer!

@DanielCusumano If you found the answer helpful, you may consider accepting it.

done! Sorry I'm new to stack overflow
